# Lucene query parser: convert ConstantScoreQuery to SpanQuery

Tags: lucene

I have a custom "phrase query parser" develeped by some third-party who is not available. 
That parser rewrites several query types into SpanQueries (each type in some different way). 
The problem is that it was written for Lucene v3 and now I'm migrating my search to L. v4, and that parser started getting another type to rewrite (ConstantScoreQuery), which was not expected before and now it's not handled by this parser.

Could someone help me and explain how to convert that ConstantScoreQuery into one of the SpanQuery types??

Best regards,
Piotr

Answer (score 0):

[`ConstantScoreQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/ConstantScoreQuery.html) is a wrapper.  It's quite possible it is still producing a `SpanQuery` (or whatever other query type was expected), which is then wrapped with the `ConstantScoreQuery`.  I'd see if `ConstantScoreQuery.getQuery()` returns something you can use.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I figured out that actualy it wraps a filter, not query. The next thing is now what to do with this filter?? Can I simply ignore the whole wrapper query, or the filter should be further processed somehow??

Comment: Without more details about how you are using it, it's hard to say for sure, but I would say you probably can't safely ignore it.  You might try saving it, and after you have your final query on the rest, pass it into your `search` call (ie. if you were using `search(int, Query)`, then you can add it by using the call `search(int, Query, Filter)`).